# Is it possible to be able to read this seemingly disorganized CSV file in C#?

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, delimiter

I'm given a large CSV file with very odd formatting and field names and that sort of thing. Say for example we have these two records:

```
Text18;Text30;Text5;Text6;Text7;Text27;Text14;Text9;Text11;Text19;Text12;Text13;Text24;Text32;Text4;Text34
Supervisor:;Tom Stringer;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Ethan Whitehouse;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;Date In;;Time In;Date Out;;Time Out;Break Time;;;Total Hrs.;;WageRate;;DLC
Monday;;10/31/2016;8:42 AM;;10/31/2016;;5:41 PM;0.00;Hrs.;8.98;;Hrs.;;33.40;$300.04
;;;;;;Total:;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;0.00;Hrs.;8.98;;Hrs.;;33.40;$300.04
Mark Smalley;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;Date In;;Time In;Date Out;;Time Out;Break Time;;;Total Hrs.;;WageRate;;DLC
Monday;;10/31/2016;8:48 AM;;10/31/2016;;4:10 PM;0.00;Hrs.;7.37;;Hrs.;;29.00;$213.63
;;;;;;Total:;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;0.00;Hrs.;7.37;;Hrs.;;29.00;$213.63
```

I need to be able to find (for this example) Mark Smalley, and his total DLC. So basically I need Mark Smalley = $213.63. I need to be able to add these dollar amounts to an array. Is there a good way to do this? I have very little control over how the data is formatted/delimited.

Comment: Looks like the data should have been put into a format that handles hierarchies like XML or JSON.  All you can do is write your own code to parse it based on whatever rules govern it.

Comment: What do you mean with _"I have very little control over how the data is formatted/delimited."_? If the csv file is different every time you receive it I don't see any chance to parse it.

Comment: it's not disorganised at all. Try opening it in Excel and you'll see a pattern. In fact it probably got that way by someone just saving a spreadsheet to a delimited file. It's not a great structure but once you see the pattern it's easy enough to loop through the fields until you come to the ones you want. You just need to tell your code which fields to look in, they will be in the same place relative to each other every time, assuming the file format is the same each time you receive it.

Comment: @rohanharrison Try [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) it's great for parsing csv files, even with multiple formats in a file and it's free.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel The format will be the same, but the data will be different.

And by I have little control over it, I mean I am given this CSV by someone else.

Comment: the problem is your text seems to have line feeds in! I got round this by taking a line, splitting it by field separator, if that didnt have enough, add the ones from the line below.. then you have lines you can work with

Comment: OK, but in this case it is as @ADyson already said. The data is not disorganised. You have one header row, one with the supervisor, one with the user name and so on. In the end you have 5 lines that make up all the data for a single user. I would build a class for that where the constructor receives an array with the 5 relevant lines and then extracts the data you need. Whenever you need mor data from the five lines extend the object and the parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this CSV file into a jagged array:

```
var myCsv = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MyStuff\CSV.txt");
var myCsvArr = myCsv.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var myData = new string[myCsvArr.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < myCsvArr.Length; i++)
{
    myData[i] = myCsvArr[i].Split(';');
}
```

Then I guess accessing the elements will be easy.